# How to throw build error if assembly referenced in package directory but not in package.config

Tags: nuget

I had a latent build error come up today because we had a .csproj that was referencing an assembly in the nuget `packages` folder, yet that package was not referenced in the project's packages.config.

Is there a nuget command line tool/API, or other simple mechanism (e.g. build convention library) that can check for this problem?

Comment: had this problem multiple times (sometimes coworker accidently check in the csproj-changes but not the packages.config or merge-conflicts). the most simple mechanism to get this detected was to cover the solutions with CI-builds (automated builds triggered by checkin/push)

Comment: Yeah this was caught by a CI build, problem was it built happily for months before breaking - happenstance with the ordering that references were added etc. Looking for something more cast iron

Comment: make sure the ci-builds clears the sources-directory (that contains the packages-folder) before the build. That should make this more reliable